# Replace text between two tags within html string - Javascript RegEx?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags, velo

I have a string containing html that is outputted from Wix Studio. I am trying to manipulate and put back within the original tags. So far I have managed to strip the tags and manipulate the string (wrapping each letter in a ), but I can't figure out how to put the manipulated string (inner) back within the original tags, desired outcome below. Won't always be `<h1>`, could be `<h2>` through to `<h6>`, potentially a `<p>` - Unable to use jQuery!

```
// Get string from Wix using the Wix Editor Elements ($w) APIs)
var html = $w('Text').html;

var string = html.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ''), 
    wrap = string.replace(/\w/g, "<span>$&</span>");
```

`html` returns `"<h1 class="wixui-rich-text__text">Add a Title</h1>"` ✅ All good

`string` returns `"Add a Title"` ✅ All good

`wrap` returns `"<span>A</span><span>d</span><span>d</span> <span>a</span> <span>T</span><span>i</span><span>t</span><span>l</span><span>e</span>"` ✅ All good

**Desired result:**

The original html tag with the modified content within:

`output` to return `"<h1 class="wixui-rich-text__text"><span>A</span><span>d</span><span>d</span> <span>a</span> <span>T</span><span>i</span><span>t</span><span>l</span><span>e</span></h1>"`

A bit out of my depth, may be a better way to go about.

Many thanks!

For ref: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/text/html

Comment: It's best to avoid processing HTML with regular expressions. Parse it to DOM objects and modify that.

Comment: Makes sense, but I’m not sure if that is possible using the JavaScript api available from Wix?

Comment: JavaScript has a built-in HTML parser.

Comment: Something like `let output = html.replace(string, wrap);`?

Comment: That’s correct @Yogi, I haven’t stumbled across this if you do have any pointers, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will suit your needs:

```js
html.replace(/(?<=(<([^>]+)>[^<>]*))\w/ig, '<span>$&</span>');
```

Test Input string:

```
<div><h1 class="wixui-rich-text__text">Add a Title</h1><p>Test <b>Again</b></p></div>
```

Output String:

```
<div><h1 class="wixui-rich-text__text"><span>A</span><span>d</span><span>d</span> <span>a</span> <span>T</span><span>i</span><span>t</span><span>l</span><span>e</span></h1><p><span>T</span><span>e</span><span>s</span><span>t</span> <b><span>A</span><span>g</span><span>a</span><span>i</span><span>n</span></b></p></div>
```

Comment: That's great, thank you @ray

Answer (score 0):

a better way is to parse it as DOM and manipulate it

```js
const html = '<h1 class="wixui-rich-text__text">Add a Title</h1>';
const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = html;
fragment.append(wrapper);
const el = fragment.firstChild.firstChild;
const content = el.innerHTML;
el.innerHTML = content.split('').map(c => `<span>${c}</span>`).join('');
const modifiedHtml = el.outerHTML;
console.log(modifiedHtml);
```